# Структура данных с упорядоченным списком с последующим сохранением в файл

Tags: c++

Managed C++.
Есть данные: группы данных и в каждой группе целочисленные данные. Например:
Завод->
5 столов
4 стулья
2 шкафа
Офис->
10 столов
8 стульев
3 шкафа

Каким образом лучше всего организовать сохранение этих данных, последующую запись в файл и возможность чтения в будущем в таком же упорядоченном списке?
Т.е. допустм, будет список групп (офис, завод) в comboBox и при выборе мы получали данные о кол-ве стульев, шкафов из сохраненного файла.

*Я вспомнил в чем у меня была загвоздка, почему я не сразу взял структуры. Данные: офис, завод динамические. Мне неизвестно сколько этих мест будет. Как быть?*

Comment: Приведите Ваши структуры данных в C программе. Тогда можно будет конкретно подумать об их записи-чтении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хрестоматийный вариант - создать структуры с соответствующими полями, заполнять их и сохранять в файл как бинарные данные кусками с фиксированным размером, потом считывать.

Пример записи

```
struct Data {
  char Place [20];
  int Chair;
  int Tables;
};

struct Data Work = {"Завод", 100, 50};
struct Data Office = {"Оффис", 70, 40};

FILE* f = fopen ("database", "wb");
fwrite (&Work, sizeof(struct Data), 1, f);
fwrite (&Office, sizeof(struct Data), 1, f);
fclose (f);
```

Если же данных много, то лучше организовать базу данных, типа MySQL

Comment: "и сохранять в файл как бинарные данные кусками с фиксированным размером, потом считывать."
Можно пример, ссылки, подробнее?

Comment: Пример записи добавил в свой ответ. Надеюсь, как читать такой файл Вы сами разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо. Т.к. я перешел на ооп недавно, для меня это важно. Я слышал, что можно целые структуры записывать, но не представлял, как это выглядит. В каком виде записываются в файл.

Comment: Ну, это не ООП. Это в стиле С. Можно записывать с помощью объектов классов ввода-вывода. 

Но вообще-то, если хотите сделать что-то серьезное, используйте нормальные базы данных.

Comment: Тут несерьезное. Тут обучение. И я осознаю, что это не ООП. Просто мое изучение началось с C#, где все гораздо "человечнее", чем в managed c++ на мой взгляд :)

Comment: Я вспомнил в чем у меня была загвоздка, почему я не сразу взял структуры.
Данные: офис, завод динамические. Мне неизвестно сколько этих мест будет. Как быть?